# Convert Option<u32> into Result<u32, Self::Error>

Tags: rust

My function needs to return a Result<u32, Self::Error> but I have no idea how to get there, seems really complicated compared to C.

```
fn myfunc(&self) -> Result<u32, Self::Error> {
  let r: Option<u32> = optretfunc();
  return r;
}
```

When I compile I get

```
return r;
^^^ expected `Result<u32, Error>`, found `Option<u32>`
```

Comment: that linked question is totally different

Comment: The only difference is the error type. It's `String` in there, and `Self::Error` here. You should use `ok_or()` or `ok_or_else()`, just like in the answer of the linked question.